# Object missing when using optim function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

This is my first time using the optim function in R, and I am having some trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong.

I want to find the maximum for the phi function. I am optimizing over the vector C.

```
Phi <- function(C, mu, sigma, xbar, P, alpha){
  X <- xbar+ P%*%C
  return(mu %*% X - alpha * t(X) %*% sigma %*% X)
}
```

mu, sigma, xbar, P, and alpha are predefined scalars, vectors, and matrices.

The gradient for the phi function is:

```
Gradient <- function(C, mu, sigma, xbar, P, alpha){
  X <- xbar+P%*%C
  n <- length(C)
  grad <- rep(0,n)
  for(j in 1:n){
    grad[j] <- mu - 2*alpha*t(X) %*% sigma
  }
  return(grad)
}
```

I tried using the optim function as below:

```
results <- optim(par = start, fn = Phi, gr = Gradient, method = "CG")
```

"start" is a predefined vector with the same dimensions for C.

However, when I try running the optim function, I get the following error:

```
> results <- optim(par = start, fn = Phi, gr = Gradient, method = "CG")
Error in xbar + P %*% C : 'xbar' is missing
```

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any guidance! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I defined my start vector as such-

```
Start <- function(n){
  vector <- rep(1/n, n)
  return(vector)
}

start <- Start(length(mu)-1)
```

Comment: You are declearing function with `xbar` argument but you do not define it in optim function. You should check your `start` vector. Could you show how you declared it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly stated by @Maciej, you have additional parameters `mu, sigma, xbar, P, alpha`, which are declared, but not supplied to an `optim()` call.

To supply these parameters, an ellipsis `...` can be used, where you specify them in a form `name=value`.

Here's a small example of how a function with parameters can be optimized:

```
f <- function(x, param) sum((x-param)^2)
optim(par=c(0,0,0), fn=f, param=1:3)
$par
[1] 1.000538 1.999985 2.999919

$value
[1] 2.966097e-07

$counts
function gradient 
     112       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```